# Having problem with the date picker, is always behind with one day

Tags: reactjs, datetime

I am having a problem with a date picker, always behind with one day no matter what changes I am doing, change the timezone but it is still the same.

Added a new item to the API, thats the date I have:

```
2019-07-17T00:00:00.000Z
```

Doing the modifications to change the date to 18:

```
2019-07-17T23:00:00.000Z
```

It changes the time just from 00 to 23: but I want the date to be changed from 17 to 18.
I am using materialui date picker, my code that I use is:

```
this.state.fields['active'] = new Date(this.state.fields['active']).toISOString()
```

I tried to use moment but is the same thing:

```
moment.tz("UTC").format(application['active'], 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: toISOString() always returns time in UTC. On what object do you change the date? Maybe it is in timezone UTC+1

Comment: I have to change on the application['active'], I think it is, how can I do the changes?